# Scheduled local notification and timezone changes in iOS

Tags: ios, timezone, scheduled-tasks, uilocalnotification

I have this method in my app to fire scheduled local notifications:

```
- (void)scheduleNotificationForTime:(long long)atTime
{
   NSDate *fireDate = [DatesMngr getDateFromLongLong:atTime];

   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   if (localNotif == nil)
       return;
   localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
   localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

   localNotif.alertBody = @"Active Status";
   localNotif.alertAction = @"View Details";
   localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
}
```

It works fine if user does not change her timezone in her device's Settings, but the notification is not launched if she changes the timezone after it has been already scheduled but not launched yet. I've also tried with `[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` with no success. Is there any way to detect these timezone changes and refresh the `fireDate` for already scheduled local notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways

1. implement the following method in your appdelegate

> - (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application

2
. Register for `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` in notificationcenter

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTimeChange:)]`;

Comment: Thanks, but this will only work if, after changing the time-zone in device's settings, the app becomes active again and I get the already scheduled local notification and re-set its `timeZone`, right? What if the user simply changes time-zone and she doesn't opens the app again before the time I wanted the notification to be launched?